# Bookshelf(knex) - belongsToMany relation not working

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, bookshelf.js, knex.js

I have been trying to setup a relation between Posts and Tags using belongsToMany relation (Bookshelf). Here is my code:

**db.js**

```
const Post = bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'posts',
    hasTimestamps: true,
    tags: function(){
        return this.belongsToMany(Tag)
    }
})

const Tag = bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'tags',
    posts: function(){
        return this.belongsToMany(Post)
    }
})

// Pivot table
const PostTag = bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'posts_tags',
    post: function(){
        return this.belongsTo(Post)
    },
    tag: function(){
        return this.belongsTo(Tag)
    }

})
```

Get route is:

```
.get('/:id', (req, res, next) => {
        db
            .Post
            .where('id', req.params.id)
            .fetch({widthRelated: ['tags'], require:true})
            .then((data)=> {
                return res.json({data, ralation: data.related('tags').toJSON()})
            })
    })
```

I have already added a table 'posts_tags' in database and all the database is seeded including this pivot table. So when I query in route, the relationship query does not even initiate. knex debug:  **sql: 'select `posts`.* from `posts` where `id` = ? limit ?'**

**Tables**

posts - id  title  text  created_at  updated_at

---

tags - id name  created_at  updated_at

---

posts_tags - id post_id tag_id  created_at  updated_at

---

Is there any mistake(s) in code?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for this Post - I had just the typo:

```
.fetch({widthRelated: ['tags'], require:true})
```

widthRelated = withRelated!!!!!!